# Express and Socket.IO shared cookies

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, socket.io

After a successful authentication of a user, it's session data is encoded into an access token, and then the following code is used to set the cookie:

```
res.set('Set-Cookie', cookie.serialize('access_token', token, {
    httpOnly: true,
    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 // 1 week
}));
```

Later, the user tries to make a `socket.io` connection and the server tries to retrieve the cookie data:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log("SOCKET CONNECTED");
    console.log(socket.handshake.headers.cookie);
    console.log(socket.request.headers.cookie);
});
```

Output

```
SOCKET CONNECTED
io=Y8-CmNDnIH1eOx0_AAAA
io=Y8-CmNDnIH1eOx0_AAAA
```

As you can see, the cookie only contains one property named `io` but not `access_token`. Though if the cookies are read on express request, they contain the token and the values are correct.

**Why are the cookie headers set on express request are different from the ones on socket.io. How do I share cookies between socket.io and express?**

Comment: Are you 100% sure the cookie was set before the socket.io connection was created?  Do you see the cookie on other express requests to prove that it's there?

Comment: FYI, you may want to use `res.cookie()` for setting the cookie since that's built into Express.

Comment: Keep in mind that `socket.handshake.headers.cookie` is a snapshot of the cookies at the time the socket.io connection was originally made.  It is not the current value of the cookies that a new http request would see.  So your cookie has to be set before the socket.io connection is connected in order to see it there.

Comment: I am totally sure that the socket connection is made after the cookies are set

Comment: Then, you need to verify that the cookie is there on another express request to make sure you are correctly setting the cookie.

Comment: Well, after the cookie is set - the client is redirected to a path, where the cookie value is loged (correct) and only then the socket connection is made. After all this, I can kill the server and launch it again. The cookie value (without reseting) will remain correct on express and incomplete in socket.io. So I'm sure about that one as well

Comment: And the socket.io connection is made to the exact same host name as the cookie is set on?

Comment: Well this is how I initialise `app = express(); server = http.createServer(app); io = require('socket.io')(server);`, so I believe - yes. Also on the client side I tried setting the socket host to `http://127.0.0.1:9639`, `http://localhost:9639` and leaving it undefined, but I've got the same result in all situations..

Comment: How does the client connect?  Is it using the exact same domain as the web page that the cookie was set in?  That's what I'm asking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159303/discussion-between-qualphey-and-jfriend00).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the socket.io connection to see your cookie, you have to make the socket.io connection from the client to exactly the same host name and port (same origin) as the one that you set the cookie on.  The browser will only send previously saved cookies to the exact same origin they were set on.  For example, you can't use an IP address in one place and locahost in another even if they resolve to the same physical server.